# Text rendering deformed upon updating MacOS to Catalina

Tags: java, text, rendering, macos-catalina, java-2d

The Java SE 8 app I'm developing needs to run on Win10 and MacOS, and I'm using a Font (Ariel) that renders well on both platforms:

Here is an example of how it normally looks (MacOS 10.13):[image]

I was surprised by how mangled and distorted the same text gets rendered after installing MacOS 10.15 (Catalina):[image]

Has anyone run into this problem?...it looks like a complete collapse of anti-aliasing.  Nothing in the Java code was changed, and the app uses the "getSystemLookAndFeel" flavor of UIManager.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the Java JRE for MacOS got seriously broken with MacOS 10.15 (Catalina), and had to await Oracle's release of JDK 14 to work correctly.  I installed JDK 16.0.1, and then in my Eclipse project, reassigned the JRE to 16.0.1 (was 8.0.101).

The text rendering problem cleared up.

Comment: This problem deserves a "root cause" explanation.   What I posted was limited to "I changed the MacOS and JRE environment, and that fixed it."

This doesn't really help someone who is experiencing the same text rendering problem under a different scenario.   Can someone speak to the root cause of these "jaggies"?